# Change Masonry layout at different screen widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) and need to change the grid layout depending on the current screen width. I'm using `.resize()` but I only need to change the layout whenever a breakpoint is crossed. For example:

```
(person changes window size)

    if over 800
    run function

    if less than 800
    run function
```

I can do this. However, it would run the function on **every** resize call. I just need to run the function if the user has crossed the boundary:

```
if window resized from 500 to 900 
run function
```

What would be the best way to fire a function, **only if they've crossed an 800 breakpoint**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple debounce function

```
$(window).on('resize', (function() {
    var o, u;

    return function() {
        var w = $(this).width();

        if (w >= 800 && !o) {
            o = true; u = false;

            $('body').append('<div>Over 800</div>');
        }else if (w < 800 && !u) {
            o = false; u = true;

            $('body').append('<div>Under 800</div>');
        }
    }
})());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6QHh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify that the event fire in the way you describe, you can however just implement such logic in the eventHandler for the resize event.

You should store the size and check against it for this kind of behavior:

```
function resizeHandler() {
    var newWidth = $(window).width();
    if (window.lastWidth > 800 && newWidth <= 800) {
           // size went from above 800 to below 800
    } else if (window.lastWidth < 800 && newWidth >= 800 ) {
           // size went from below 800 to above 800
    } 
    // else border not crossed
    window.lastWidth = newWidth;
}
window.lastWidth = $(window).width(); // default to window size at beginning
$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your computationally intensive function inside a checker that make sure it is only executed when the threshold is crossed.

```
var bool = $(window).width() < 400;
$( window ).resize(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 400 != bool) {
        bool = !bool;
        console.log($(window).width());
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2gMfC/1/

Comment: I'm resizing like mad but nothing seems to get logged?

Comment: @tmyie, I changed it from 800 to 400 because the fiddle runs inside an iframe and `$(window).width()` gets the iframe width

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom event and add an event listener to call your function.

```
function emitEvent(evt, obj, bubbles) {
     if (typeof evt != 'string') return false
     if (!window.customEvents) window.customEvents = {}
     var customObject = typeof obj == 'object' ? obj : {};
     var eventBubble = typeof bubbles == 'boolean' ? bubbles : false;
     window.customEvents[evt] = new CustomEvent(evt, {
         detail: customObject,
         bubbles: eventBubble,
         cancelable: true
     });
     this.dispatchEvent(window.customEvents[evt])
}
```

call emitEvent('myevent') once the window is resized to a breakpoint of your choice and add an event listener eg. window.addEventListener('myevent',myfunc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for using external libraries, [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) is made exactly for this. (I'm not affiliated with the development of enquire.js)

You set it up like this:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 800px)", {
    match : function() {
        // Your function here
    }
});
```

You can see an **[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5Xc/)**.